# WebStorm will open at most 2 instances

Tags: webstorm, multiple-instances

I am able to launch WebStorm from the command line with `webstorm .` I am able to have two different projects: `A` and `B` (in this order) running in two separate instances of WebStorm. Nevertheless, when I open a third one `C` , `A` instance disappears. When then I close `C`, `A` reappears.

Is it a feature or a bug?

How can I have all `A`, `B`, `C` projects open at the same time?

Comment: **FYI:** those are NOT instances as WebStorm does not work like that. I mean: If you launch the same IDE version / executable then it will be the same instance just a **separate frame** (window). To really have a **separate instance** the IDE must be configured to use different config files / different sys folders (indexes/caches/etc) and have different installations: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/tuning-the-ide.html

Comment: As for your question: are you able to open the 3rd project from within the IDE? What's your settings at `Settings/Preferences | Appearance & Behavior | System Settings` for project opening. If you can open more than 2 frames from within the IDE and unable to do the same via command line launcher then it's a bug (and I do remember seeing something like that in the past)

Answer (score 1):

I am able to open more than 2 projects at the same time. However, I have 32 GB RAM. Depending on how you configured WebStorm, each instance consumes considerable memory. If you only have, say, 8GB RAM you won't be able to open very many projects at once.